# How to use Expo.DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync properly. [Expo] [ReactNative]

Tags: react-native, expo

I've tried to restrict file types that can be selected by Expo.DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync, but without success.

How to filter many mimeTypes at once?

I already tried as follow:

```
Expo.DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({type: "image/*;application/pdf"});
```

and

```
Expo.DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({type: "image/*,application/pdf"});
```

and

```
Expo.DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({type: ["image/*","application/pdf"]}); //CRASH
```

I'm using sdk 27.0.0.

Some suggestion? Expo team? :}

Reference:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/document-picker#type-string----the-mime-type-of

Answer (score 1):

`expo-document-picker` now accepts an array of MIME types like

```
 getDocumentAsync({type: ["image/*","application/pdf"]});
```

Refer: [this documentaiton](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/document-picker/#documentpickeroptions)

Comment: Yes, through the lasts SDK updates, now is possible to filter MIME types directly on getDocumentAsync, as you show.

Before that, we did a small check after the event of selecting a file from expo file system, throwing a message that show to user what kind of files are allowed. =D

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it seems that we can't pass multiple mime types on document picker of expo as it is of string type and not an array. Also there's an open issue regarding the same [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/4263)

I tried to implement similar to this using any one of the following MIME types to upload certain file types only:

```
let result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
      type: "*/*" // all files
      // type: "image/*" // all images files
      // type: "audio/*" // all audio files
      // type: "application/*" // for pdf, doc and docx
      // type: "application/pdf" // .pdf
      // type: "application/msword" // .doc
      // type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" // .docx
      // type: "vnd.ms-excel" // .xls
      // type: "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" // .xlsx
      // type: "text/csv" // .csv
    });
```

for other MIME types, checkout [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type)